# Appium how to find TextField InputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium to do some tests on my application.

I think I'm facing an issue. I have a `UITextField` which has a custom `inputView` and a custom `inputAccessoryView`.

My custom `inputAccessoryView` is like "Cancel" - "Title" - "Validate" (2 buttons and 1 label).

I can't find the locator of button "Validate" using Appium Desktop. I can find only object of `inputAccessoryView("XCUIElementTypeOther")` but there is no child.

Do you have any idea how to retrieve this element to perform a click action? (I tried to set `isAccessibilityElement` to true, accessibilityIdentifier/Value/Label..., but it doesn't works)

Thanks for your help.